# Scraping Google results without getting blocked

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing some code to scrape information from Google search results. Ideally, I would like to be able to scrape around 1000 results (urls) based on a set of keywords. Now, I'm getting reguraly blocked (temporarily) for sending too many requests. This usually happens after around 300 results (titles/urls) are scraped from the Google Search results. Lately, I've been reading a lot on how to circumvent this, however without much luck.

Now, I would like to obtain the maximum amount of results without getting blocked. Specifically, I would like reduce the amount of requests I'm sending. This would ease the pressure on the web, therefore reducing the likelihood of getting blocked. However, I do not know how to implement this while opening the website with `urllib.Requests` and `urlopen.read()`. Any help on this? Btw, I do not mind obtaining 1000 URLs over the course of, say, 3-4 hours. Code below:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import time
from time import sleep

user_agent_list = [    
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.56',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
    ] 

# Scrape URLs based on Google keyword combinations
root = "https://www.google.com/"
url  = "https://google.com/search?q="

csv_fn = 'export.csv'

def news(link, n_pages=5, page_count=0):
    print(page_count)
    
    sleep(random.uniform(5, 10))
    
    # Insert a session somewhere here?
 
    req = Request(link, headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
        
  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

    for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi'}): # 'kCrYT' for larger link string
        start_time = time.time()
        
        try:
            title = (item.find('div', attrs= {'class': 'BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd'}).get_text())
        except:
            print('No title found')
            continue
        
        # Export to CSV
        document = open(csv_fn, "a", encoding='utf-8')
        document.write("{}\n".format(title))
        document.close()

    nextPage = soup.find('a', attrs = {'aria-label': "Volgende pagina"}) # Or 'Next'
    if nextPage is None:
        nextPage = soup.find('a', attrs = {'aria-label': "Next"})

    # Only continue to next page if present!
    page_count += 1
    if nextPage is not None and page_count < n_pages:
        nextPage = (nextPage['href'])
        link = root + nextPage
        news(link, n_pages=n_pages, page_count=page_count)
    elif page_count >= n_pages:
        print(f'Scraped {n_pages} pages, done!')
    else:
        print('No next page found, terminating scraping...')

link = url + 'whale+watching+orca+iceland'
news(link, n_pages = 5)
```

Btw other tips to prevent Google from blocking are all very welcome. Although it seems that tips such as IP rotation, for free, are a bit too much to ask when scraping Google results.

Comment: Please remove the "nlp" tag and instead add the "beautiful-soup" and "urllib" tags. Further, is there any reason for using urllib and not using https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html?

Comment: You're already using `sleep` in your code, if you want to wait longer between requests simply increase the sleep time.

Comment: @l4mpi yes I'm aware that I'm using sleep, however even with the sleep command I obtain a "Too many Requests" error after ~ 300 items. So just sleep is not cutting it.

Comment: @GaneshTata. Well the reason I'm not using requests is that I could not find one effective way to scrape the titles from each next Google Results page. If you have any example/link that shows this I would love to check it out.

Comment: @CrossLord. If the Selenium answer below is not working for your purposes, please share why it is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Selenium for this. It lets you automate usage of google chrome and permits usage of JavaScript, making the solution less reliant on parsing.

I also tested this method and it with the query you provided. It ran out of pages after 25 pages or ~250 titles.

I am not entirely certain how you want your CSV structured, so Ill just show you how to get the news titles.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

csv_fn = 'export.csv'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) #Get Automated Google Chrome Drivers
driver.maximize_window()

def google_search(query):
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q') #Search bar
    search_box.send_keys(query) #Type query
    search_box.submit()         #Hit Enter
    time.sleep(2)

    #Find news tab
    tabs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("hide-focus-ring")
    for tab in tabs:
        if tab.text == 'News':
            news_tab = tab
            break
    driver.get(news_tab.get_attribute('href')) #Go to news tab

query = 'whale watching orca iceland'
google_search(query)
num_pages = 0
while num_pages < 200:
    try:
        time.sleep(random.uniform(5, 10))

        #Perform title extraction logic here
        headings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@role = 'heading']") #Heading elements
        for heading in headings:
            title = heading.text
            #Do whatever with the title
            print(title)

        #Go to next page
        next = driver.find_element_by_id('pnnext') #Next page
        next.click()
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: #No more pages
        break

    num_pages += 1

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input deseuler. However, I'm getting this error when running your script:


ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a class="hide-focus-ring" href="/search?q=whale+watching+orca+iceland&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=nws&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjwhou75dPwAhV55-AKHZw1AroQ_AUoA3oECAEQBQ" data-hveid="CAEQBQ">...</a> is not clickable at point (491, 107). Other element would receive the click: <img src="data:image

Comment: It seems like something is obscuring the news tab in the chrome browser. I updated the code to be a little more generalized in finding the news tab and go to it without using the click method. Let me know if this change fixes it.

Comment: Thanks again. The previous error is resolved, but now I'm bumping into this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'news_tab' referenced before assignment".

Comment: That means the news tab is not showing up in your driver. I cant reproduce this issue.